# How to pass empty params to express in a get?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a route that I call with Angular, typically: server/a/b/c 
Server side I want to query my DB with the req.params. 
Just trim and omit if a: '' or b : '' 
However express does not like paths like server//c. 
Is there a way to handle this?
I could transform the route to /null/null/c but that's ugly :s.

Comment: why not move optional parameters to the end? 
or use query strings instead?

Comment: All of them are optional (the route: doSomethingOnServer/:a/:b/:c). 
Query string like ?a= etc, ? That does not look clean.  
I'm thinking about using an array ['a','','c'] ...

Comment: Having multiple optional query parameters does not seem intuitive to me. Instead you can set up multiple different routes: 
`/server/:a/`,
`/server/:a/:b`,
`/server/:a/:b/:c`
All common code can be shared via middleware (e.g. `compose`), then controller can control logic specific for each variation

Comment: Indeed that's a cleaner way, I'm surprised that requests like server/a//c can't be handled :s.